# st_geometry<-.data.frame(*tmp*, value = value) : inherits(value, "sfc") || is.character(value) is not TRUE

Tags: r, dataframe, tmap

I am trying to plot a percentile map with the following data frame

DF1 - Covid_DF - [Province, City, District, Sub_District, Cases, Death, Month, ID]

DF2 - DKI_Jakarta- [Object_ID, Village_Code, Village, ID, Province, City, District, Sub_District, Total_Population, Gemoetry]

I've combined them in the following way

```
Jakarta_Covid_Cases <- Covid_DF %>%
  inner_join(DKI_Jakarta, by=c("Sub_District"="Sub_District")) %>%
  group_by(Sub_District, Date) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(`Covid Cases Per 10k Population` = (sum(Cases) / (Total_Population / 10000))) %>% ungroup()

Jakarta_Covid_Cases <- Jakarta_Covid_Cases%>% left_join(DKI_Jakarta, 
                       by=c("Sub_District"="Sub_District"))

Jakarta_Covid_Cases<- st_as_sf(Jakarta_Covid_Cases)
```

Now I would like to plot a Box map and I've created the two function - Box Map and Get.var (which is working fine -I've tested with other dataframe)

```
# To create break points for box map
boxbreaks <- function(v, mult=1.5) {
  qv <- unname(quantile(v))
  iqr <- qv[4] - qv[2]
  # upfence and lofence define the area where points will be defined as outliers
  upfence <- qv[4] + mult * iqr
  lofence <- qv[2] - mult * iqr
  # initialize break points vector
  bb <- vector(mode="numeric",length=7)
  # logic for lower and upper fences
  if (lofence < qv[1]) { # no lower outliers
  bb[1] <- lofence
  bb[2] <- floor(qv[1])
  } else {
  bb[2] <- lofence
  bb[1] <- qv[1]
  }
  if (upfence > qv[5]) { # no upper outliers
  bb[7] <- upfence
  bb[6] <- ceiling(qv[5])
  } else {
  bb[6] <- upfence
  bb[7] <- qv[5]
  }
  bb[3:5] <- qv[2:4]
  return(bb)
}

# Extract variable as vector out of sf dataframe
get.var <- function(vname, df) {
  v <- df[vname] %>% sf::st_set_geometry(NULL)
  v <- unname(v[,1])
  return(v)
}

# Boxmap function
boxmap <- function(vnam, df, mtitle, legtitle=NA, mult=1.5, palette='-RdBu') {
  df1 <- drop_na(df)
  var <- get.var(vnam,df1)
  bb <- boxbreaks(var)
  tm_shape(df) +
    tm_fill(vnam,
            title=legtitle,
            breaks=bb,
            palette="Blues",
            labels = c("Lower outlier", "< 25%", "25% - 50%", "50% - 75%","> 75%", "Upper outlier")) +
  tm_borders(lwd=0.1, alpha=1) +
  tm_layout(main.title = mtitle,
            main.title.position = 'center',
            main.title.size = 1,
            frame = FALSE) +
  tm_scale_bar(width = 0.15)
}

# Boxmap function with points overlayed on top of choropleth map
boxmap_pts <- function(vnam, df, pointdf, mtitle, legtitle=NA, mult=1.5, palette='-RdBu') {
  boxmap(vnam, df, mtitle, legtitle=legtitle, mult=mult, palette=palette) +
  tm_shape(pointdf) +
    tm_dots(col="gray23")
}
```

Now I would like to plot a box map using my function

```
dd_boxmap17 <- boxmap("Covid Cases Per 10k Population", Jakarta_Covid_Cases, mtitle="Jakarta Covid Cases (Mar 2020 - July 2021)")
dd_boxmap17
```

I am facing the following error- Error in `st_geometry<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = value) : inherits(value, "sfc") || is.character(value) is not TRUE

Comment: A small snippet of the data would be really helpful here.  My guess is that one of your columns is a factor instead of a character.

Comment: Here you go -  Screenshot of Covid_DF, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1s60mHjqMFu-UVmJhQJIeXJcsVX3wyhhl/view?usp=sharing, Screenshot of DKI_Jakarta    https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aGEqN62NGiO8B-JdIVy-GwOOq3tzlHQ0/view?usp=sharing. Here's the rds - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gXHjtrVa-IlxhQNjHqOrqL8HVWJpjhOo/view?usp=sharing, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QLWc6qLHyr3HP2FYjgwlLQKMpW2k3IbH/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I got to a map by changing the get.var function:

```
get.var <- function(vname, df) {
  v <- df[vname] # %>% sf::st_set_geometry(NULL)
  v <- unlist(v) # unname(v[,1])
  return(v)
}
```

gives:
[image: Box Map]

Comment: The debugger was a big help here.  debugonce(boxmap) and debugonce(get.var)

Comment: I thought this was a good answer.  Please upvote/accept if you think so too.